# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{x\to \infty} (1-\frac{2x+1}{2x-1})^x$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

how can I solve this limit without using l'hopital.

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\right)^x$$

Comment: The problem is ill-posed. The base is always negative when $x > 0$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Well, no: the problem isn't wrong. This would be an excellent Calculus I question for the students to pay attention **first of all** to what the expression whose limit is asked really is...In this case, the expression is ill-defined...but the good student *must* come up with that!

Comment: The expression simplifies to $(\frac{-2}{2x-1})^x$.  The limit looks like $0^{\infty}$

Comment: Point of terminology: You ask, "how can I solve this integral?" There is no integral here. I think you mean, "how can I *evaluate* (not solve) this *limit*?"

Comment: Ah! Yes, I just noticed. My apologies.

Comment: I disagree with the vote to close the problem with the reason "the problem is wrong" - isn't the point of this site to teach why things are wrong?

Comment: @DonAntonio At least the OP should change the title for his problem --- he can't ask people to "calculate" something that is not-calculable. If the problem is formulated as "does the limit of *expression* exist?", then it is a perfect problem

Comment: @Zhanxiong Maybe the OP didn't even notice the "function" whose limit he wants is ill-posed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left(1-\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\right)^x=\left(-\frac2{2x-1}\right)^x=\ldots$$

the expression isn't well defined for infinite values of $\;x\;$ when $\;x
\to\infty\;$ and thus the limit cannot be taken.

Comment: Why can not I take positive values?. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it's because it's an oscillating limit, right?

Comment: @trick15f Because $\;-2<0\;$ whereas $\;2x+1>0\;$ since $\;x\to\infty\;$ and we can assume $\;x>0\;$ all the time...

Comment: @trick15f Nothing oscillating here: the expression whose limit you wanted **is not well defined** when $\;x\to\infty\;$ as the basis of that power is *negative* .

Answer (score 0):

$$ \left(1-\frac{2x+1}{2x-1}\right)^x=\left(\frac{-2}{2x-1}\right)^x$$

thus the limit exist only for $x\to -\infty$, set $y=-x\to +\infty$

$$\left(\frac{-2}{2x-1}\right)^x=\left(\frac{2}{2y+1}\right)^{-y}=e^{-y\log{\frac{2}{2y+1}}}\to +\infty$$

Comment: Didn't you read the other (my) answer and/or the comments below the question?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes I've read your interpretation of the OP. I guess that from your point of view the limit for $x \to \infty $ should be interpreted in a rescritive way as a limit for $x \to +\infty $ and $x \to -\infty $?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking: the limit when $\;x\to\infty\;$ means that the given function of $\;x\;$ must be evaluated when larger and larger (positive) values of $\;x\;$ are taken. What has $\;-\infty\;$ to do with this?

Comment: @DonAntonio sometimes I've seen the notation $x\to \infty$ for $|x|\to +\infty$

Comment: I've never seen such a thing, but even if it existed I presume we should be warned and correspondingly said by whoever uses such a bizarre convention.

Comment: @DonAntonio To avoid misunderstandings I  always prefer specify $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Comment: Exactly my point and thus in this exercises, as is usually assumed in 99.99% of the cases *at least*, the intention is, unless otherwise specifically said, the limit when $\;x\to\infty\;$ and **not** $\;x\to \color{red}-\infty\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio I understand your point but when I read $\to \infty$ always check both $\to +\infty$ and $\to -\infty$ :)